# Azure Management API with service principal: The subscription '[...]' could not be found

Tags: azure-management-api, azure

I have created a subscription with Azure Germany, and now I am attempting to deploy my application topology there using the Azure Management API and a service principal.

Deployment works fine towards the "regular" Azure cloud, however when I attempt to deploy towards my subscription in Azure Germany, I get the following error message: **The subscription '[...]' could not be found**.

I am able to successfully acquire an authentication token using `AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync()`, and I am using "https://login.microsoftonline.de/[directoryId]" as *authority* and "https://management.core.cloudapi.de/" as *resource*. Additionally, I am using "Germany Northeast" as *location/region*.

The error occurs as soon as I attempt to perform a typical management task, such as creating a resource group.

I have checked the following things:

- App registration settings
- App permissions (Windows Azure Active
  Directory + Windows Azure Service Management API)
- Correctness of
  subscription id, app id, and app secret/key

I am at a loss at what could be wrong. What could be causing this error message?

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 0):

you should point your app to correct subscription first.
Try setting subscription using this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/kubernetes/container-service-kubernetes-service-principal).
Add Microsoft Graph permissions to your Azure AD app.